# Can I back reference modified capture using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expression in python. What I already know about re is that I can use pattern like `"([a-z]{2,4}) is \1"` to match `"food is food"` in the text `"I think food is food."` or `"cat is cat"` in the text `"I think cat is cat."`

What I want to do now is to match some inverted sequence, like `"food is doof"`, or `"cat is tac"`, which requires a modified back reference.

Is there anyway to match this using regular expression? Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: No, you cant do this through regular expression only.

Comment: What I was trying to do is match some DNA motif in a long sequence. So the motif is buried in the sequence. We don't know where the motif begins, so we cant use "^" to match the head of the sequence. @AvinashRaj

Comment: use this `(?<!\S)` instead of the staring anchor.. Which asserts that the match wouldn't be precede by a non-space character.. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AvinashRaj An real life example would be a pattern: `p1=2..4 TA ~p1`， which means pattern start with p1 with 2 to 4 letters, followed by letters "TA", followed by reverse complement(do some substitution after reversing) of p1. Then I need to locate the pattern `p1=2..4 TA ~p1` in a sequence formed by about 1000 `[ATGC]`

Comment: There is the possibility of extending the regex engine with your own syntax to match the reversed text. There is no such facility in any of the regex engine I know of, maybe save for Perl with arbitrary code execution inside the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved！
There is a feature in perl's regex called dynamic regex(or something like that), where you can insert you code into regex and get the returned value. This is used as (??{code}). 
In my case, the code would be:

```
/([a-z]{2,4})(??{reverse($1)})/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't find a regexp for any length, the best you can do is a regexp for a specific length.

E.g. for a 4-letter word :

```
([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])([a-z]) is \4\3\2\1
```

Comment: Thanks, you have solved my original post. However, what I want is to match a length range, like {2,4}.